# How to get information about the satellites from android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the satellite information from the android and wrote this following code which is not giving any results, could any one point out why is it so?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);

    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
    if(gpsStatus != null)
    {
         Iterable<GpsSatellite>satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
         Iterator<GpsSatellite>sat = satellites.iterator();
         int i=0;
         while (sat.hasNext()) {
             GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();


             strGpsStats+= (i++) + ": " + satellite.getPrn() + "," + satellite.usedInFix() + "," + satellite.getSnr() + "," + satellite.getAzimuth() + "," + satellite.getElevation()+ "\n\n";
         }
     }
     TextView tv = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.Gpsinfo));
     tv.setText(strGpsStats);
}
```

thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the docs for `LocationManager.getGpsStatus(...)`...

> This should only be called from the `onGpsStatusChanged(int)` callback to ensure that the data is copied atomically.

Try implementing `GpsStatus.Listener` on your Activity and overriding `onGpsStatusChanged(int)`. Example...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GpsStatus.Listener {

    LocationManager locationManager = null;
    TextView tv = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gps);

        tv = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.Gpsinfo));
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int) {
        GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
        if(gpsStatus != null) {
            Iterable<GpsSatellite>satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
            Iterator<GpsSatellite>sat = satellites.iterator();
            int i=0;
            while (sat.hasNext()) {
                GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
                strGpsStats+= (i++) + ": " + satellite.getPrn() + "," + satellite.usedInFix() + "," + satellite.getSnr() + "," + satellite.getAzimuth() + "," + satellite.getElevation()+ "\n\n";
            }
            tv.setText(strGpsStats);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please allow me to ask a stupid questions:  What is "strGpsStats"??  A string??

Comment: @Rich : I assume so based on its 'str' prefix and the fact it's used to set the text of a `TextView`. I was simply modifying the OP's code from their question which had strGpsStats in it.

Comment: The GpsStatus is deprecated. So, how can I access the satellite info?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 LocationManager locmgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     //locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10L, 5.0f, this);
     Location location = locmgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

     if ( location == null ) {
         location = locmgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

     }
     if ( location == null ) {
         location = locmgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

     }
```

Let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

GpsStatus.Listener is deprecated. You should use LocationListener and GnssStatus.Callback instead.
Here following code:

```
import android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.GnssStatus
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
...

class YourFragment : LocationListener {
    
    private var mGnssStatusCallback : GnssStatus.Callback? = null
    private lateinit var mLocationManager: LocationManager

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mLocationManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        mGnssStatusCallback = object : GnssStatus.Callback() {
            override fun onStarted() {
                Log.e(TAG, "GnssStatus.Callback onStarted")
                super.onStarted()
            }

            override fun onSatelliteStatusChanged(status: GnssStatus?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GnssStatus.Callback Status: ${status?.toString()}")
                super.onSatelliteStatusChanged(status)
            }

            override fun onStopped() {
                Log.e(TAG, "GnssStatus.Callback onStopped")
                super.onStopped()
            }

            override fun onFirstFix(ttffMillis: Int) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GnssStatus.Callback onFirstFix $ttffMillis")
                super.onFirstFix(ttffMillis)
            }
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }

        mGnssStatusCallback?.let {
            mLocationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(it)
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0F, this)
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this)
        mGnssStatusCallback?.let {
            mLocationManager.unregisterGnssStatusCallback(it)
        }

        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged new Location: ${location.toString()}")
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged p0 ${p0 ?: "null"} - p1 ${p1}")
    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled p0 ${p0 ?: "null"}")
    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled p0 ${p0 ?: "null"}")
    }

}
```

Note:
I have observed that the GnssCallback may arrive in some minutes after you request for Location update.