# Glonass satellites are supported or not?

Tags: android, detect, capability

How can be detect if an Android based mobile device is supporting glonass capability or not?

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/technologies/glonass/

Comment: Great link :) Combine that, with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6721071/833647

Comment: Guys, Thank you of your answers!
It is a really great article about GLONASS satellites!

Answer (score 2):

That could be a bit difficult, or not.  It depends on the Android platform implementation.

The default framework that Google provides does not carry information for any constellation except GPS.  You could be using Glonass and just not see the satellites show up because the Framework has no way to pass this info from the hardware device driver to the Framework.

Some device manufacturers have implemented a small change in the default Framework that allow it to carry glonass satellite info.  This is a simple change (one line of code) in the Framework but it must also be matched by equivalent changes in the GPS hardware device driver.  You can't use one change without the other.

If you start seeing satellite ID numbers greater than 32, you know it is showing some other constellation.  I think Glonass satellites normally use the range of 65 to 88, but I could be wrong about that.  There should always be more than one Glonass satellites in the sky for every location on earth.  If you see them, then you know your device has that capability.  If you don't see them, it doesn't prove anything for sure because some devices only enable glonass usage if there aren't enough GPS satellites.

Answer (score 2):

Install GPS Test app [available here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) and check the ID of measured satellites. From 65 to 96 are GLONASS.

(E.g. http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/06/GPS_Test_application.jpg )

Comment: I am seeing in my own app that I sometimes see multiple GLONASS satellites directly overhead, with SNR ratios as high as or higher than other satellites, yet the "in use" flag is always false. Why would that be?